# Which module to use for connecting to Cassandra using NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, cassandra, npm

I wish to integrate Cassandra with Node, column families in my schema leverages composite key & column support extensively. When I browsed NPM I could find many Cassandra connectors viz. (below list order by search results) 
cassandra
connect-cassandra
cassandra-orm
cassandra-client
cassandra-helenus-api

Which of these support composites? I do not see detailed documentation of these, any pointers?

Answer (score 2):

We use [helenus](https://github.com/simplereach/helenus) in production. It supports both Thrift and CQL. There are good examples of how to use the library (including composites) in the project's test directory.

Answer (score 2):

The preferred Node.js driver for Apache Cassandra is now [datastax/nodejs-driver](https://github.com/datastax/nodejs-driver). It is based on the node-cassandra-cql project from Jorge Bay and will be maintained by DataStax going forward, so that's what should be used for new projects.